# Wine doesn't run 90% of my games correctly, display is hugely magnified

Tags: wine, games, nfs

I have many games on my PC including GTA 3, NFS MW, San Andreas, Vice City, but the wine program loader doesn't seem to work on them. The game is magnified so much that I can see only the top right corner of it (which covers the whole screen) and after I close the wine program loader, I have to log out of my admin user to resume my work.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you're experiencing problems with wine, the best place to ask are the [Wine forums](http://forum.winehq.org). Also, you may want to use PlayOnLinux, a frontend for Wine, which ships with setup scripts for various games and software.

Comment: If all you want to do is play windows games, run windows. Linux, with or without wine, is not a drop in replacement for windows. If you need help see https://appdb.winehq.org/ . wine configuration is very often very specific to a game or version of wine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only working methods for gaming with Linux is Steam or with native games (like Baldur's gate and Neverwinter Nights). Gaming with wine will be not as good as gaming it natively on Windows. Your hardware is never going to fully used when using wine.

All those games you mention will have each their own quirks and their own installation method. The [play on linux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) package that accompanies wine gets you a long way; that system works with community created script files.

For each of the mentioned games the link will open the POL script:

- [GTA3](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-239-Grand_Theft_Auto_3.html)
- [Vice City](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-225-Grand_Theft_Auto__Vice_City.html)
- [Need for speed; most wanted](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-748-Need_For_Speed_Most_Wanted_Patch_13.html)

---

- [San Andreas](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-3203-Gta_san_andreas.html) should be even easier. It has an entry in Play On Linux.

Good luck with this but if you want to do gaming with all hardware at your disposal either use a dual boot or a virtual installation. Or a console.

Comment: i have play on linux on my system but it doesnt run any games. for me, its just a hoax! I even tried installing them through play on linux yet they didnt work